# Problem with distribution of random variable which is a sum of function's values

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I need to find distribution of the random variable $Y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}f(U_i)$, where
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & \textrm{when $x_1>x_2$}\\
0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
$$
and $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_n$ are i.i.d. with the same distribution as $U$, $U=(X_1,X_2)$, $\gamma=P(X_1>X_2)$.
My question is: how to find distribution of $Y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}f(U_i)$?

I have tried to do it this way (by checking the behaviour of distribution for different numbers):
$P(Y=1)=P(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}f(U_i)=1)=P(x_1>x_2)=\gamma,$ 
$P(Y=2)=P(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}f(U_i)=2)=?.$ 
I'm thinking about this problem for a long time and still I don't know how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n$ independent trials, each with probability $\gamma$ to success and you count successes. Hence: $Y\sim Bin(n,\gamma)$  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

So, for example:
$\Pr(Y=1)=n \gamma (1-\gamma)^{n-1}$ because you need one $U$ to be 1, and the rest zeros.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The answer seems to be easy then, it is simply Binomial distribution.

Comment: @Beginner Welcome to MSE. If you found this answer helpful you should consider accepting it. (It’s the check mark to the left of the answer.)

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist thanks for explaining the rules. I have already accepted the answer.

Comment: @Beginner No problem! Hope you find the time you spend here worthwhile.